# Should there be filters to de-/select versions of a language and thus documentation?

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Getting the hang of [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation), I tried to learn by example and checked the Array topic on Java https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays#t=201607212100242092915

I noticed that this applies for versions 1.0 to 8:

[image]

So far so good.

---

Looking at the sorting example, I noticed that contributors created a section specific to JDK 1.8+

[image]

I know that 1.8 and 8 are the same thing when it comes to java, but somebody new to the topic does not. *Are Java SE 8 and SDK 1.8 the same thing?*
As everybody can introduce their own system to denote the different versions, examples and documentation overall will become inconsistent.

I propose that there should be some mechanism in place to mark an example (better: parts of an example) to be usable for a specific version or range of versions of a language. As the user selects a version from a drop down, only those examples (parts of them) appropriate for that version are displayed.

If you look at [ActionScript 3.0 Reference for the Adobe Flash Platform](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/), you can see such filtering in action:

[image]

It has been said that documentation aims to be better than other documentations, but in this regard I feel like it's beaten *by* a dead horse.

Could we improve and introduce some system as proposed above or come up with a better one?

Comment: Someone already fixed that http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/21111